# regex pattern expressions

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a expression for a field with the pattern as `[0-9]*` which takes a numeric value followed by a `*` ex. `0123*****`. But I want to also include the pattern of `*****0123` in the same expression. How can I do it in java. Right now it is as follows

```
 String numericPattern = "[*0-9]";
```

Comment: If we're talking regex that's not what it means. `[0-9]*` means any number of digits.

Comment: * is a wildcard used in RegEx to signify 'any number of'. If you want to match against * characters, you have to escape it by preceding with a /. So /* will match against * characters. /** will match against any number of * characters. Not very confusing! Or is it?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want

```
^\**\d+\**$
```

which means any numbers of asterisks (`\**`), followed by at least one digit (`\d+`), and then again, any number of asterisks (including zero) (`\**`). Since `*` is a special character in regex (a quantifier  meaning *any number of the preceding character/class/group*), it has to be escaped with `\` to match a litteral `*`.

The start of line (`^`) and end of line (`$`) anchors ensure nothing else **but** the matched pattern is present.

Note that in java you'll have to escape the backslashes though, so you should end up with something like

```
String numericPattern = "\\**\\d+\\**";
```

[See an example here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9jFrDq/1).

Comment: I think she wants to enforce at least 1 asterisk before or after. This would match a single digit.

Comment: @Meenal Do you have anything to comment on the answers you've gotten?

Comment: Now it takes all the formats- i.e. 1234***** and *******1234 and ***1234****

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
(\*+\d+)|(\d+\*+)
```

---

Breaking it down:

```
(\*+\d+)
```

A literal asterisk `\*` one or more times `+` followed by a digit `\d` one or more times `+`.

```
|
```

or

```
(\d+\*+)
```

A digit `\d` one or more times `+` followed by a literal asterisk `\*` one or more times `+`.

---

As [ClasG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064981/clasg) said, you'll need to escape the slashes in Java, so your pattern would look like:

```
String numericPattern = "(\\*+\\d+)|(\\d+\\*+)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The star character is a quantifier in a regular expression. If you literally mean the star character you have to escape it. The following expression allows one or more stars followed by one or more ciphers or one or more ciphers followed by one or more stars.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\*+[0-9]+)|([0-9]+\\*+)");
```